# Как узнать формат даты?

Tags: java, android, json

Как узнать формат даты, если он неизвестен заранее?

Суть вот в чем: получаю данные JSON, у разных объектов дата обозначена в разном формате, например у Васи День рождения в формате `yyyy-MM-dd`, а у Пети `dd-MM-yyyy`, но может появиться и Саша с абсолютно новым форматом в будущем.

Мне нужно каждую дату привести в единый формат `dd:MM:yyyy` на уровне класса, реально ли это сделать, не зная входящий формат?

Comment: Да никак. Допустим 02.05.1985 может быть пятое февраля, а может 2 мая. Ничто не способно понять, что у вас там появится. Никто еще не придумал алгоритма как определить число или месяц стоит вначале. Есть у вас Вася с д.р. 02.05.1985. Потом появляется Петя с д.р 02.05.1985 (только родился он 5 февраля). Ну и всё. Вот тут и проблема.

Comment: Если вы получаете данные в формате JSON, то вы с вероятностью 99 процентов делаете запрос на сервер по API, а API в сервере просто так не меняется. А еще есть такое понятие, как версия API. Она гарантирует, что ничего не изменилось, если версия осталась неизменной. Если исходить из того, что API  меняется произвольно, то боюсь, что у вас будут гораздо более серьезные проблемы, чем распарсить дату... В любом случае можно контролировать версию API , чтобы гарантировано получать данные в формате, который вы умеете читать.